# Webpack urls not correct

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, build-tools

I'm having trouble with webpack resolving the URL's correctly. When running on my local node server (Because it's handy) it works like a charm but when I upload it to my server it stops working once I put it in a subfolder (http://hostname.com/folder) if I put it in the root it's fine.

My image that I load in JS via require break. They are place inside an 'assets' folder in the root of my project. But it searches in the root of the server.

Webpack Config:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var path = require('path');

var config = require('./_config'); //paths config..

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        config.build('js', 'src'), //JavaScript entry point
        config.build('css', 'src'), //CSS entry point
    output: {
        path: config.js.dest.path,
        filename: config.js.dest.file //JavaScript end point
    }, //quickest, webpack -d -p for production
    devtool: 'eval',
    module: {
        //test: which filetype?,
        //exclude: which folders to exclude
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel',
            query: {
              babelrc: path.join(__dirname, '.babelrc')
            }
        }, {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'eslint'
        }, {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css!postcss!sass?outputStyle=expanded')
        }, {
            test: /\.json$/,
            loader: 'file?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=../assets/[hash].[ext]'
        }, {
            test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
            loaders: [
                'file?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=../assets/[hash].[ext]',
                'image-webpack?{progressive:true, optimizationLevel: 7, interlaced: false, pngquant:{quality: "65-90", speed: 4}}'
            ]
        }]
    }, postcss: function(){
        return [
            require('postcss-will-change'),
            require('postcss-cssnext')({
                browsers: ['IE >= 10', 'last 2 version'],
                features: {
                    autoprefixer: {
                        cascase: false
                    }
                }
            })
        ]
    }, //webpack plugins
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        //extract CSS into seperate file
        new ExtractTextPlugin(
            config.build('css', 'dest')
        )
    ], eslint: {
        configFile: path.join(__dirname, '.eslintrc'),
        ignorePath: path.join(__dirname, '.eslintignore')
    }, resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.json', '.js', '.css'],
        fallback: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')
    }, resolveLoader: {
        fallback: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')
    }
};
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set [publicPath](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-publicpath) to point at your asset directory. Example:

```
output: {
  path: config.js.dest.path,
  filename: config.js.dest.file,
  publicPath: 'assets'
}
```

In addition you need to tweak your loader definitions like this:

```
loader: 'file?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=./assets/[hash].[ext]'
```

After doing these tweaks your application runs for me without any errors.

Comment: I tried your solution but still no succes:

`Phaser.Loader - image[cuberdon]: error loading asset from URL /assets/../assets/58e500fe3b4f0ae0d28707150235895f.png`

Comment: Can you set up a runnable example on GitHub? It's hard to say anything concrete without. `publicPath` is clearly doing something. I'm just not sure of that ´..` bit.

Comment: You can find it here: https://github.com/JannesV/Major3 It's a school project so don't expect too much :)

Comment: That works, sorta. It now searches for the files in the right directory. ie the root of my folder/assets but it saves the in the JS folder/assets

![example](http://i.imgur.com/Stk8ztP.png)
That is how it is now. But I want my assets in my root. Not part of the JS folder.

Comment: I think you need to combine these two. `publicPath` can be used to adjust that behavior in particular.

Comment: Yeah I can't get it to work. Nothing I try works. I've already wasted 2 days on this.

Comment: It seems to be fixed using that. Thanks !